# Can you cast a Subtle Spell while under the effects of Hold Person?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

Let's say that you're a Sorcerer under the effects of Hold Person, can you cast a spell without a material component with the Subtle Spell metamagic?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### No, you cannot cast

The problem is not with movement or speech (ie. performing components), but that *hold person* subjects you to the paralyzed condition:

> A paralyzed creature is incapacitated (see the condition) and can't
> move or speak. (PHB 290)
>
> An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions. (PHB 290)

The victim is incapable of taking actions and thus cannot cast spells at all. Not even with a bonus action, as:

> anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also
> prevents you from taking a bonus action. (PHB 189)